# Erro de codificação utf-8 Python

Tags: python, git, unicode

Boa tarde a todos sou iniciante a programação Python, estou criando um programa que lê a informação de um texto e transcreve em outro lugar.

Aparentemente o texto estava funcionando normalmente no computador, subi todas essas informações no `github`, quando gerei esse arquivo em um novo computador ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 1: invalid continuation byte.

Tentei adicionar o alguns novos parametros:

```
file = open(r'Query.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
```

Mesmo assim sem sucesso.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

talvez por que seu arquivo "Query.txt" não esteja em utf-8?? Experimente trocar o "encoding" por "latin-1" em vez de "utf-8":

```
file = open(r'Query.txt','r',encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou.